# How to manipulate log file using grep or awk?

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, logs

I'm trying to get over the /var/log/secure log file, and show **only the "Failed Password" log type, which appear at least 3 times..**
There is any way to do that using linux commands only? awk? grep?

An example for secure log,

```
Mar 20 08:38:28 localhost sshd[21895]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=mail.queued.net user=root 
Mar 20 08:38:31 localhost sshd[21895]: Failed password for root from 207.210.101.209 port 2854 ssh2 
Mar 20 15:38:31 localhost sshd[21896]: Received disconnect from 207.210.101.209: 11: Bye Bye 
Mar 20 08:38:32 localhost unix_chkpwd[21900]: password check failed for user (root) 
Mar 20 08:38:32 localhost sshd[21898]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=she
```

from this log file I expect **say nothing** because there is only 1 Failed Password line,
but lets say there  were 4 lines of "Failed Password", with the same IP - I want to display the IP address which probably trying to brute force me..

Comment: can you post the sample contents or /var/log/secure log file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a way to do the job. Instead of username, I prefer count how many times a specific IP address try to connect to my host, because then I can eventually ban it.

```
awk '/Failed password/{ z[$11]++; } 
     END{ 
       for (i in z){ 
         if (z[i]>3) printf("%s attemps %s times.\n", i, z[i])
       }
}' /var/log/secure
```

(Of course it can be a oneliner command, I indented to increase readability.)

Explanation:

`awk` reads the log file line by line.
If a line contain the string `/Failed password/` increment an array element `z[$11]++` index by `$11` (i.e. the IP address): I use this as a counter. At the end, search in the array `z[$11]` and print only the IP addresses that have tried to connect more than 3 times.
You can customize the check and the print message as you like.

---

If your concern are the brute-force attempts, may I suggest you to use an existing tool as [Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) which scans log files and bans IPs that show the malicious signs (for examples: too many password failures, seeking for exploits, etc..). It's easy to understand and configure to fit your needs.

Comment: Can you please explain your solution? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to execute that script via subprocess as you can see :

`p=subprocess.Popen(["awk '/Failed password/' {z[$8]++;}END {printf("lala")}'
secure"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)`

and I'm getting syntax error.
Every thing works fine, except for the print inside the END { },
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '/Failed password/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/for/)user[$(i+1)]++}END{for(j in user){if(user[j]>3){printf("%s : %s times failed\n",j,user[j])}}}' /var/log/secure
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, then I think, your answer does not do, what OP is asking for.

Comment: can you explain what OP is asking for ? if you have sample contents of secure file, can you post...

Comment: /var/log/secure holds lines like "DATE HOST DAEMON: Failed Password for user kamaraj ip 12.34.56.78 port 3456". (I think) he wants the usernames/IPs, that have tried/failed 3 times or more.

Comment: hmm.. lets wait for OP to provide the exact requirement and example file contents...

Comment: Yeah, I'm also waiting for clarification.

Comment: I'm using Linux, red hat.

Comment: This is example of secure log file: Mar 20 08:38:28 localhost sshd[21895]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=mail.queued.net  user=root
Mar 20 08:38:31 localhost sshd[21895]: Failed password for root from 207.210.101.209 port 2854 ssh2
Mar 20 15:38:31 localhost sshd[21896]: Received disconnect from 207.210.101.209: 11: Bye Bye
Mar 20 08:38:32 localhost unix_chkpwd[21900]: password check failed for user (root)
Mar 20 08:38:32 localhost sshd[21898]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=she.....

Comment: can you post the contents in your original question with code alignment {}

Comment: {Mar 20 08:38:28 localhost sshd[21895]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=mail.queued.net user=root Mar 20 08:38:31 localhost sshd[21895]: Failed password for root from 207.210.101.209 port 2854 ssh2 Mar 20 15:38:31 localhost sshd[21896]: Received disconnect from 207.210.101.209: 11: Bye Bye Mar 20 08:38:32 localhost unix_chkpwd[21900]: password check failed for user (root) Mar 20 08:38:32 localhost sshd[21898]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=she}

Comment: from this log file contents, whats your expected output ?

Comment: I've edit my question as you can see..

Comment: modified the answer.. give a try